# Form Dynamic Tag Manager

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to tracking this form https://secure-www.seat.com/content/lu/brand/fr/contact/arrange-a-test-drive.htx with Dynamic Tag Manager (DTM)of Adobe.

I've create a Rule Based Event like this:

- Event Type --> Submit
- Apply event handler directly... (In fact I try with check and uncheck)
- Element Tag --> form

The same rule, with my personal page form is successful: http://pujoljulia.com/ (!Hablémos! link). As you can see I used form Tag selector, but also I tried other, button, div... and rule doesn't trigger ever.

However, in both pages the Click Map listener recognized event. Honestly I try all options and I can't see why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to tracking this form
>   https://secure-www.seat.com/content/lu/brand/fr/contact/arrange-a-test-drive.htx
>   with Dynamic Tag Manager (DTM)of Adobe.

I took a look at your page and there it looks like DTM is not being loaded on that page.  I could not find the _satellite object.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic form handlers on sites that have customized forms are fairly unstable, usually one or the other breaks. I did not look too deeply to the seat.com page, but it looks to me like JavaScript is used to override default behavior and this could be causing the problem. Clicks do get registered, but this would not solve your problems, as

What I would suggest is that you move the tracking to the next page, where the form has been submitted. This is far more reliable and has a lower chance of causing issues. Usually you can use URL parameters or page naming variables to target on these pages.